# Serialized Object Ontology

Tags: xml, json, serialization, object

kind of a student with this...
I've been reading up on json and serialized object notation generally,
also its relation to xml. What I can't figure out or find info on,
Is there some sort of umbrella term/field there, covering data objects
that you pass between applications, how to optimize them, etc?

If I wanted to learn about json and other things that accomplish the 
same function, is there a search term, or some term to give amazon, or
anything (searching 'json' gives me sites about json, searching 'xml' gives 
me sites about xml, with no crossover or interrelation)?

I'm not sure this is a programming question per se, but I
would appreciate any tips. Thanks.

Comment: I guess the fine point is, how does a student approach this stuff? Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd guess [Data serialization format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category%3aData_serialization_formats) or [Markup language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markup_language) are what you're searching for. Of course the latter is mostly on Markup, which is designed to be human-readable - and even though both JSON and XML are human-readable, the term might be a bit to general.

Comment: I've been reading up on this YAML too, Data Serialization Format really helps.